# Sorting the values while using geom_bar(stat="identity")

Tags: r, ggplot2

#### Problem

I'm using `ggplot2`, and I am currently stuck at the following problem. I have the following dataset, which can be reproduced.

```
library(tidyverse)
TestDF = data.frame(Effect1 = rnorm(100, 10, 1), Effect2 = rnorm(100, 5, 1)) %>% 
  arrange(Effect1) %>% mutate(IDs = 1:100) %>% 
  melt(measure.vars = 1:2 , variable.name = "Effects")
```

Since I would like it to be plotted with `x` sorted according to the values of `Effect1`, I have put `arrange(Effect1)` to the dataframe. Then I plotted using the following code:

```
ggplot(TestDF, aes(IDs, y=value, fill=Effects)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", alpha = .7)
```

And the problem I have encountered : the plot has "general" trend of increasing values of `Effect1` (as we see from the left to the right), but is never sorted exactly according to the values of `Effect1`.

---

#### What I tried

I have tried

```
TestDF$IDs = factor(TestDF$IDs, levels=1:100)
```

but it never fixed my problem. Any other solutions (or bypasses)?

Comment: If you want to sort every Effect level, you will need to think of a visualization where both levels do not share the `x` axis. Unless I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like barplot is doing what you want, but order of Effects makes it looking wrong.
If Effect1 is below Effect2, plot is looking right.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

TestDF = data.frame(Effect1 = rnorm(100, 10, 1), Effect2 = rnorm(100, 5, 1)) %>% 
  arrange(Effect1) %>% mutate(IDs = 1:100) %>% 
  melt(measure.vars = 1:2 , variable.name = "Effects")  %>% 
  mutate(Effects = factor(Effects, levels = c('Effect2', 'Effect1')))

ggplot(TestDF, aes(IDs, y=value, fill=Effects)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", alpha = .7)
```

[image]